# EF 5 Code First : The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 Code First. When I try to using `DbContext` I get the following error :

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

`InnerException` is :

> Cannot open database "MyDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user '**sa**'.

Database doesn't exist. In the following code I check database is exist or not to create it based on my domain changes.

```
if (context.Database.Exists() ||
    context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
{
    context.Database.Delete();
}
```

Connection string :

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\sql2012; Initial Catalog=MyDb; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=*****"
```

**Update :** DbContext usage :

```
public class DomainDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DomainDbContext()
        : base("WebMarkerConnection")
    {

    }

    public IDbSet<ServiceUser> ServiceUsers { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ServiceUserConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FavoriteConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryConfig());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Can you put your code where you have used DbContext?

Comment: In the exception message said:`Login failed for user 'sa'`.

Comment: @Saber Amani: i am asking the class that is inherited from   DbContext and not the connection string

Comment: @HamletHakobyan : thanks for reply I can read exception message, but everything is OK user id is SA which is SQLServer's sysadmin user and password is correct.

Comment: If you have mixed authentication mode on your sql server, can you try to connect with this connection string `connectionString="Data Source=.\sql2012; Initial Catalog=MyDb; Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=True;`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan no I still have same error. it doesn't work.

Comment: You still have `Login failed for user 'sa'.` error? Fantastic!

Comment: Where are you get error (on which row of code)?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to something going wrong with my SQLServer 2012 ?

Comment: Here `context.Database.Exists()` when I want to check database.

Comment: Do you have Windows/SQL server authentication turned on for that database?

Comment: @RyanBennett Yes server authentication is windows/sqlserver .